# Headset for 41mm steering tube, 1 1/8 to 1 1/4 tapered fork

Tags: headset

I have titanium tapered fork, 1 1/8 up and 1 1/4 bottom and a titanium frame with a steering tube which uses integrated bearings, the inner diameter where the bearings sit is about 41 mm, could be 42 mm I don't have a caliper handy, but since I used a cane creek headset with a 1 1/8 non tapered fork I assume 41 mm. This fork broke (bent rather) in a crash.

I wonder if there is a way to be able to use this tapered fork work with the frame. I have been doing some research and I am aware you can make certain tapered forks work with certain non tapered steering tubes and some manufacturers made specific headsets for that. But I haven't yet found a solution for my particular setup, unless I am missing something. I am fine doing some adjustments such as filing and honing. I've done that with steel frames to make certain things fit.

I have a feeling though there is not a lot or anything which can be done, easily, to make this work. An external cup at the bottom could work, if the steering tube was not made for an integrated bearing. But I can imagine it could be made to work with some kind of insert to allow a cup to be pressed in.

Comment: wait -- if the fork is bent, I don't think you should be doing anything with it besides admiring it on your wall or recycling it somehow (I'm not sure if titanium can be recycled as easily as e.g., aluminum and steel)

Comment: The fork I am replacing is bent, and yes it is now used as decoration. :-) I have a replacement which was never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the headtube lower is IS41 or IS42, there's no way of doing this short of a very elaborate fabrication project. Even that would likely result in introducing some kind of adapter between the frame and the headtube that would screw up the geometry.

Comment: Yes I was suspecting that as well, thanks for confirming. I'll mark it as accepted answer soon if nothing else comes along.